# Rx Java vs Rx C#

Tags: java, c#, rx-java, rx-android, rx.net

I am starting to learn Rx for C# [with this ebook](http://www.introtorx.com), but since I also work a lot with Java I am wondering about how Rx for C# and Rx for Java may differ. This way I can learn one and then just focus on the differences between them to finally learn both.

What discrepancies I might expect from Rx for C# and Rx for Java? How they differ from each other? What are their limitations? What one accomplishes that the other can't?

Comment: One could write an entire book about the differences. Or, you could just read an RxJava book too.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping they would be very similar, same functionality and methods, just minor differences.

Comment: The problem is, you'd have to know one or the other for the differences to make sense. Listing them upfront is unlikely to be helpful before that.

Comment: I see... Well, I guess I will just try to find a good book on Rx Java with updated content. Thanks!